# Tick label position of seiyria/bootstrap-slider are not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using seiyria bootstrap slider in which tick labels are dynamic. Here you can see the ticks are correctly aligned but their labels are not.

following is the sample markup

```
<div class="container">
<div class="examples">
    <div class='slider-example'>
         <h3>Example 13:</h3>

        <p>Using ticks.</p>
        <div class="well">
           <input id="ex13" type="text" data-slider-ticks="[100, 150, 180, 300, 400]"  data-slider-ticks-labels='["$100", "$150", "$180", "$300", "$400"]' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Anuj_Kumar/qn3u9orj/11/) showing the issue

Here is an image to show the issue:

[image]

Comment: I already responded [to your issue](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/472) - what more do you need?

Comment: see the update to my answer below, that should get you sorted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the bootstrap-slider plugin in its official state (confirmed by the author in the comments below).

**However, with some tweaking to the plugin, you could make it do what you want.**

[image]

#### [jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/srsrw5bL/11/)

Specifically, this is what I changed to achieve this effect:

I changed this CSS rule (you should really override the original rule for your specific container rather than changing the plugin CSS as I have done for simplicity sake):

```
.slider.slider-horizontal {
  width: 100%; /*changed*/
  height: 20px;
}
```

I added this default option to the plugin:

```
    Slider.prototype = {
        //....
        defaultOptions: {
            //...
            modify_label_layout:false // added this option
        },
        //....
```

Then, I added these two functions to the plugin:

```
         _modifyLabelOffset: function(){
            var positions = [];
            var $sliderContainer=$(this.element).prevAll('.slider');
            var $ticks = $sliderContainer.find('.slider-tick');
            var $labels = $sliderContainer.find('.slider-tick-label');
            $sliderContainer.css('margin-bottom', '12px');
            $ticks.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var tickWidth = $this.width();
                var tickLeft = $this.position().left;
                positions.push(tickLeft - (tickWidth))
            });
            $labels.each(function (i,e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.css('width', 'auto');
                $this.css('position', 'absolute');
                $this.css('left', positions[i]+'px');
            });
            $this=this;
            $( window ).resize(function() {
                $this._delay(function(){
                    $this._modifyLabelOffset();
                }, 500);
            });
        },
        _delay: (function(){
            var timer = 0;
            return function(callback, ms){
                clearTimeout (timer);
                timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
            };
        })(),
```

I changed the initialization of the plugin to this:

```
$("#ex13").slider({
    ticks: [100, 150, 180, 300, 400],
    ticks_labels: ['$100', '$150', '$180', '$300', '$400'],
    ticks_snap_bounds: 30,
    modify_label_layout:true  // added this option to the plugin, if true the layout of the lables will be modified
}).slider('setValue', 0); // starts out at 5 for some reason, weird, for now , just set it manually to 0
```

Note that this is a bit of a hack and could undoubtedly be incorporated into the plugin in a better way. Also, I have ONLY tested this in chrome. It may not function correctly in other browsers but this shows proof of concept so Ill let you take it from there :)

---

**Original Answer:**

I believe this is a limitation of the bootstrap-slider plugin.

Note that if you use evenly spaced numbers like so:

`data-slider-ticks="[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"`

the labels are correctly positioned. [see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/qn3u9orj/12/)

The plugin will let you use small numbers relatively close together as you have done here but even [their own example page](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) displays issues with the layout when doing so:

[image]

Comment: This is a limitation. You can't have things be 100% dynamic and look 100% great for this, so you need to exercise some discretion when using it. OP already posted in our issue tracker and got a response.

Comment: @Seiyria Thanks for the confirmation. For what it's worth, I was able to tweak the plugin to get the desired effect. Though, admittedly, I have not fully tested my changes :)